# Confluent platform community edition limitations

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I'm started using Apache Kafka and Kafka Connect within Confluent Platform.
I deployed it using docker compose example: https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/7.3.0-post/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml and added needed connectors into kafka-connect.
I have one question about limitations of this deployment
Since it uses following docker images:

```
confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.0
confluentinc/cp-server:7.3.0
confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.3.0
cnfldemos/cp-server-connect-datagen:0.6.0-7.3.0
confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:7.3.0
confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:7.3.0
confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-cli:7.3.0
confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:7.3.0
```

I suppose at least one service (cp-enterprise-control-center) is enterprise version, but at this moment it works fine and I've not faced with limitations yet (I saw just one warning that I won't be deploy more than 1 brokers). Is it community edition or some "trial" of enterprise edition? Which limitations should I expect of this deployment, will it stop working after some time?

And one additional question, what deployment can you advice to run kafka-connect with kafka for low load (~1k messages a day).

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control Center is an Enterprise licensed product. Confluent Enterprise license is restricted to one broker, and the license does have a 30-day expiration beyond that.

Community is **not** a "trial".

Both are described at https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/license.html

Comment: Ok, so a I can use cp-kafka and cp-kafka-connect withount limits (for example 3 brocker per cluster)? What alternative can you advice instead cp-control-center in case I'd some web gui with more than 1 brocker?
And one more question does different images of kafka/kafka-connect/zookeeper can be used in one deployment?
For example is it possible (and is it good idea) to run docker stack with:
wurstmeister/zookiper as zookeeper
wurstmeister/kafka as kafka brocker
confluent/kafka-connect as kafka-connect
provectus/kafka-ui as web gui?

Comment: You can. [I use bitnami containers](https://github.com/OneCricketeer/apache-kafka-connect-docker). Or you use Kubernetes (minikube) with Strimzi operator which uses different images as well. Kafka + Connect are Apache licensed. Only Control Center has a limitation of 1 broker; the Docker image does not matter since Control Center is responsible for the checks. But you shouldn't run multiple brokers on one host, anyway. I suggest not mixing images because that's needlessly downloading more docker layers and taking more disk storage.